# if i want to add overlay items on map using gps

Tags: android

here is my code `enter code here`
<

```
package ntryn.n;


import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;


import android.content.Context;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;

import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Address;

import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.io.IOException;




import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ntryn extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mapController;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    Drawable drawable, drawable2 ;
    HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

        locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
            0, 
            0, 
            locationListener);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);

        // enable Street view by default
        mapView.setStreetView(true);

        // enable to show Satellite view
        // mapView.setSatellite(true);

        // enable to show Traffic on map
        // mapView.setTraffic(true);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(16); 

        mapController = mapView.getController();

        mapView.invalidate();

        GeoPoint p;
        String coordinates[] = {"30.084691643714909", "31.335958242416382"};
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

        p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6), 
            (int) (lng * 1E6));

        mapController.animateTo(p);
        mapController.setZoom(17); 

      //  HelloItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlay(drawable);
        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.clear();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        

        mapView.invalidate();
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener 
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6));

                /* Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + 
                        " Longitude: " + location.getLongitude(), 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

                mapController.animateTo(point);
                mapController.setZoom(16);

           //     GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint{"30.084691643714909,31.335958242416382"};

                // add marker
                MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
                mapOverlay.setPointToDraw(point);
                List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                listOfOverlays.clear();
                listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);

                String address = ConvertPointToLocation(point);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mapView.invalidate();
            }
        }

        public String ConvertPointToLocation(GeoPoint point) {   
            String address = "";
            Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(
                    getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(
                    point.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                    point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);

                if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                    for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                        address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

            return address;
        } 

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }




    class MapOverlay extends Overlay
    {
        private GeoPoint pointToDraw;
        private GeoPoint p1;
        public void setPointToDraw(GeoPoint point) {
            pointToDraw = point;

        }

        public GeoPoint getPointToDraw() {
            return pointToDraw;
        }
        public void setp1(GeoPoint po1) {
            p1 = po1;

        }

        public GeoPoint getp1() {
            return p1;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            // convert point to pixels
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(pointToDraw, screenPts);

            // add marker
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dotred);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y - 24, null); // 24 is the height of image        
            return true;
        }
    }



}
```

whats wrong i'm doing i want to add other overlay rather than the one appear when i open the gps at my specific location

Comment: What's your problem? It isn't clear

Comment: plz help me i want to add point in specific location how to do this while using the gps and the gps open in the place i'm in with an image so how to add other item in a location i specify

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer based on the (little) info you gave.

Your code shows a MapOverlay that draws a bitmap over one point.

1. In the `onCreate()` method of your application you create MapOverlay and add it to the list of overlays of yout MapView, **but you never call `setPointToDraw()` so you end up with a null GeoPoint**
2. You are always clearing the list of overlays before addind a new one, so you always end up with one overlay.
3. If you want to display multiple points you can use [ItemizedOverlay](http://code.google.com/intl/es-419/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html)
4. If you want to display the users current location you can use [MyLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/intl/es-419/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html)

Comment: @ aromero >>You are always clearing the list of overlays before addind a new one, so you always end up with one overlay.!!
what do i do clean all the list ?!!

Comment: listOfOverlays.clear(); 
This clears the list, that is, it removes all elements.